# PHP: How to add more parameters to filter_var() to match also specific domains?

Tags: php, validation, email

I have an html form with an email field that I want to validate. I'm processing the form with PHP, so I used the `filter_var()` function.

The thing is that I *ALSO* want to filter emails that does not contain three specific domains after the `@` sign (like the email inserted should be filtered if it is not legal, AND if it is not `@example.com`, `@example2.com` or `@example3.com`).

How may I do that?:

```
<?php
if (!filter_var($_POST['emailRemitente'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Oops! Not a valid email";
    } else { ...
```

Comment: You could do an `explode()` on the `@` and check the second array value if it matches any of the banned.

Comment: As rasclatt said, something like `in_array(explode("@", $_POST['emailRemitente'])[1], array('example.com', 'example2.com'));` (*depending on your PHP version, you can call the returned array value*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Array of domains to be rejected - all domains MUST be lower case
$rejectedDomains = array('yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com', 'gmail.com');
// Break up the email address (assuming you have validated the email already)
$emailParts = explode('@',$_POST['emailRemitente']);
// Check if the second element (the domain) is in $rejectedDomains
if (in_array(strtolower($emailParts[1]), $rejectedDomains)) {
    // Rejected Domain
} else{
    // Accepted Domain
}
```

Comment: If you use this method of validation. Make sure you use strtolower|strtoupper to the set incoming email and your list to prevent a uppercase/lowercase input from bypassing this check. IE: test@YaHoo.com would break this

Comment: Updated to reflect John's valid concern

Answer (score 1):

MUse a regular expression

```
    if(preg_match('/(.*)(@)(example)(.*)(\.com)$/i',$email)) {
        print "FOUND EXAMPLE*.COM";
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

EDIT: i thought you were actually trying to catch "example*.com".

```
        $emails = [
        'obama@yoMaMa.com',
        'ol.dirty@bastard.com',
        'eatme@katyPerry.com',
        'pen@island.com'
    ];
    foreach($emails as $email) {
                                // Pipe | seperate domains and escape the period
        if(preg_match('/(.*)(@)(island\.com|bastard\.com|yomama\.com)$/i',$email)) {
            echo "Invalid Domain! {$email} \n";
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

Invalid Domain! obama@yoMaMa.com

Invalid Domain! ol.dirty@bastard.com

Invalid Domain! pen@island.com

Comment: the only reason I wouldn't recommend this is maintaining the pattern gets to be a bit of a chore after five domains.  After ten or twenty, most(?) people would gut it and redo it anyways.